# Why is GetExternalFileDirs not working in android?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, usb

I am working on a sample project in unity android where application reads a textfile in an OTG pen drive connected to the android phone, the problem is my code works fine in some devices but it doesn't work in some devices. I am unable to figure out the main cause even through the logcat extreme as it doesn't throw any error at all that specifies code error.

I tried adding text logs to print text in between the code to see which texts are not printed, which would further tell me that after which line code stopped working but all the texts are printed.

This is my code that detects the USB and returns true if a text file is present in USB:

```
public void LocateFile()
{

    textfileData = null;

            using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
               using (AndroidJavaObject context = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
               {
     // Get all available external file directories (emulated and USBdrives)
                 AndroidJavaObject[] externalFilesDirectories =  context.Call<AndroidJavaObject[]>("getExternalFilesDirs", (object)null);

                 AndroidJavaObject emulated = null;
                 AndroidJavaObject USBdrive = null;


                  for (int i = 0; i < externalFilesDirectories.Length; i++)
                      {
                         AndroidJavaObject directory = externalFilesDirectories[i];

                        using (AndroidJavaClass environment = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment"))
                        {         
                          bool isRemovable = environment.CallStatic<bool>("isExternalStorageRemovable", directory);
                          bool isEmulated = environment.CallStatic<bool>("isExternalStorageEmulated", directory);
                          if (isEmulated)
                          {
                            emulated = directory;
                          }
                          else if (isRemovable && isEmulated == false)
                          {
                            USBdrive = directory;
                          }
                        }
                      }

            // Return the USBdrive if available
            if (USBdrive != null)
            { 
             if (File.Exists(USBdrive.Call<string>("getAbsolutePath") + "/serial.txt"))
                {
                  textfileData = File.ReadAllText(USBdrive.Call<string>("getAbsolutePath") + "/serial.txt");

                }

             }    
  }
 }}
```

This code works on my android phone and returns true after detecting the file present in pendrive.

Can anyone tell me what could be the issue and point me in the right direction, I will greatly appreciate your support on this.

This locateFile() function is called on Update().

Update: I tried to debug the number of storage found in mobile and code is not reading the USB. It reads internal and SD storage perfectly.

Nokia 5 is the only phone the code has worked on so far but in 99% android devices GetExternalFilesDir is not reading usb storage.

Please someone tell me an alternate or how do I get this to work, it is very important.

Comment: Unclear: Is the drive not listed by "getExternalFilesDirs"? Or is it listed and you cannot write a file or determine its presents?

Comment: What is the value of externalFilesDirectories.Length? (Tell if a micro SD card is inserted in the device too).

Comment: Sorry for unclear information, It is not reading the usb at all in some devices and I checked with devices that have SD card but it does work on some devices only even with sd card.

Comment: This function returns a true only when the text file data is read and saved to a string name "textfileData" otherwise it will stay false.

Comment: `, It is not reading the usb at all in some devices` So you mean that it is not listed by "getExternalFilesDirs" and the value of  `externalFilesDirectories.Length` is one then? Please answer to the point! You did not even tell the value.

Comment: yeah, I read your question but to answer that I'll have to run code on the phone in which this isn't working and I don't have access to one now. It works in my device so will it matter if I tell you the value from my device?

Comment: Yes of course. And it is good for you to know the value too. We all know it will be 2 or 3 depending on a SD card yes or no.

Comment: yes, give me a minute I'll tell you the value I received on my phone(it has no sd card).

Comment: externalFilesDirectories.Length is 1 when no USB plugged in and 2 when USB plugged in(I have no SD card.). I am going to check the values in the devices which are not reading the textfile in USB location.

Comment: Yes. And if the usb drive is not mentioned check if it is visible when you apply Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and such.

Comment: The problem with LocateFile() is that when it returns false you do not know if the drive is not listed or the file is not found. You better make two functions.

Comment: I will not use this function as a bool method instead I will save the removable drive path if it returns true with isRemovable then further reading a specific textfile(serial.txt) int the savedLocation of the removable drive, then saving the text in a string to be used in another method of same class. Making this function a bool was a temporary thing. You pointed me in the right direction by making me checking length of externaFileDirectory.

Comment: If the usb reads in non-working device(which is to be tested yet) then we know its file reading method or locating problem but if the externalFileDirectory returns 0 or 1 (which I am wondering won't be the case),I'll look for an alternate to using getExternalFIleDirs

Comment: I changed my code to print number of external devices it reads in two other phones(Redmi note pro 5 & asus zenfone max pro m1), usb wasn't detected at all. It detected only two storage in asus, i.e. internal and sd card(which is also removable) but single storage in Redmi which is internal but none of these device detected the usb. Is there something wrong with getExternalFilesDirs?

Comment: Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: But do these phones support USB-OTG?

Comment: yes defenitely.. they both do. I have shared movies with those phones using otg.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. What is this?

Comment: To let the user pick a directory from any drive. Google.

Comment: no that is not how this works, its important that usb is detected in the app to read the text file located in it.

Comment: Try if it works on those devices. Which alternative do you have else?

Comment: I wouldn't ask here if i knew

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this issue? Please I need this working by tomorrow.